# Docker. Ошибка создания сети

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Хочу создать контейнер для локальной разработки nginx+php+mysql(пока только осваиваю докер).

Создал docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '2'

services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        volumes:
            - ./hosts:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - ./www:/var/www
            - ./logs:/var/log/nginx
        links:
            - php
        networks:
              default:
                  ipv4_address: "${NET_DEFAULT_EXT_IP}"
    php:
        build: ./images/php
        links:
            - mysql
        volumes:
            - ./www:/var/www
    mysql:
        image: mysql:8
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
            - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
networks:
    default:
        driver: bridge
        driver_opts:
            com.docker.network.enable_ipv6: "false"
        ipam:
          driver: default
          config:
              - subnet: "${NET_DEFAULT_SUBNET}/${NET_DEFAULT_MASK}"
                gateway: "${NET_DEFAULT_GATEWAY}"
```

Для удобства файл констант .env:

```
NET_DEFAULT_EXT_IP=127.10.0.10
NET_DEFAULT_MASK=16
NET_DEFAULT_SUBNET=127.10.0.0
NET_DEFAULT_GATEWAY=127.10.0.1
```

ну и конфиг nginx'a:

```
server {
    index index.php;
    server_name 127.10.0.10;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/hello.dev;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Вся эта прелесть при запуске докера выдает ошибку:

```
Creating network "testdocker_default" with driver "bridge"
Creating testdocker_mysql_1 ... error

ERROR: for testdocker_mysql_1  Cannot start service mysql: b'oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:334: running prestart hook 0 caused \\"error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: time=\\\\\\"2018-05-15T01:43:23+03:00\\\\\\" level=fatal msg=\\\\\\"failed to set gateway while updating gateway: route for the gateway 127.10.0.1 could not be found: invalid argument\\\\\\" \\\\n\\""'
```

Адреса для ip,subnet,gateway ставил разные, результат тот же самый.
При удалении networks из всех частей, контейнер запускается.

Помогите плиз кто чем может!
Перевернул кучу документации и примеров, вроде все настроено нормально.

Comment: а без указания шлюза?

Comment: К сожалению нет, та же самая ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Посоветовал бы перейти на версию docker-compose 3.

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  php:
    networks:
      - net 
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: mysql.project_net # project - `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=example` в `.env`
networks:
  net:

# Когда начинаются проблемы c docker dns. Пробуй уже с subnet.

net:
  ipam:
    config:
      - subnet: 173.1.0.0/16
```